# swapping images with rentinajs

Tags: jquery, retina.js

im using http://retinajs.com to swap out images for hi resolution devices but when it comes to changing images with jquery it doesn't seem to work for example:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#country").hover( function () { 

$("#profilePic").attr("src","img/country.png");

} );

});
```

on retina screens should be

```
$("#profilePic").attr("src","img/country@2x.png");
```

Many Thanks

Comment: did you try running `$("#profilePic").retina();` after image change?

Comment: yes doesn't seem to work :S